# Installing "Tiled" plugin into Corona Project Manager

Tags: plugins, installation, coronasdk

I'm only posting out of frustration to be frank...
Spent the past 2 hours now searching for any guides to setting up a "plugin" while using the Corona Project Manager to build my app.

I have absolutely zero coding experience, but i'm learning.

So I am trying to learn to use Tiled to build levels, I downloaded it here: http://www.mapeditor.org/
And I tried to run this sample code as a test/teaching myself: http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/corona-tiled

Running that sample code gave me some errors naturally, reading the debug errors I'm guessing I did not yet install/unpack/setup/integrate Tiled into my app. It's trying to call and read from a few .dlls and such.

So can someone please, kindly please, point me in the right direction to getting this 3rd party tool set up? Any guides or links or even a direct answer here will be much appreciated.

Many thanks waiting eagerly~